# Prevent CSS3 transform from making video element unclickable/unreachable/unfocusable

Tags: html, css, html5-video, css-transforms

I've met a serious problem today, CSS transforms makes video controls unresponsive, whole video element is unclickable and unfocusable

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/emily_robenson/pen/Yzvaaqj)

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; pointer-events: auto; width: 1095px; height: 789px; perspective: 952.407px;">
<div style="transform-style: preserve-3d; pointer-events: none; width: 1095px; height: 789px; transform: translateZ(952.407px) matrix3d(-0.999994, 0.000178028, -0.00348579, 0, 0, -0.998698, -0.0510059, 0, 0.00349033, 0.0510056, -0.998692, 0, 35.8949, 0.468229, 19.1121, 1) translate(547.5px, 394.5px);">
<video controls="controls" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="xFrame" class="xFrame" style="border: 0px; position: absolute; pointer-events: auto; display: block; width: 1920px; height: 1080px; line-height: 1080px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) matrix3d(-0.00390625, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.00390625, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.2, 0, 35.5661, 3.00001, 28.8209, 1);">
</video>
</div>
</div>
```

What are my options?

I've tried to play with z-index and couldn't make it,
also
`

```
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(1px);
```

`
has no effect

Thanks for any help

Comment: Works fine on `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0`, but the problem is reproducible on `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using the transforms on a video object? There might be an alternative way to achieve the expected result of the transform...

Comment: Works in safari also on Mac but not on an Android phone or iOS phone.  I suspect the issue may be that one of your divs is covering the video when you are on a smaller screen and the clicks are not being propagated. If this is the case and you are testing on a mobile, connecting the mobile to a browser inspector on a laptop may be a quick way to see the issue.